# How to convert a character to an ASCII code & vice versa in Nim

Tags: nim-lang

How to convert a character to a dezimal ASCII code?

So for example `"a"` should be converted to `97`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out by myself.

You can cast a `char` into an `int` with: `int('a')` or `ord('a')`.

`"a"` in Nim is a `string`, not a `char`. So at first you need to get the character you want the ASCII code from. In this case the first character inside the string.

So `int(char("a"[0]))` would give the ASCII code for the first character inside a string.

The same procedure works also in the other direction. To convert an ASCII code into a character, you do `char(97)` and get `'a'`.